# Can't restart mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble restarting mysql.  When I enter the following command, I get this message:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the restart(8) utility, e.g. restart mysql
```

And it **hangs** forever.

When I try to restart mysql as a service using the following command:

```
# service mysql restart
```

It **hangs** forever.

I can't log into mysql as root anymore either.  Any ideas on how to get this running again?

I tried the following

```
# service mysql start
start: Job is already running: mysql
```

When I do the following

```
# ps -ef | grep -i mysql | grep -v grep
```

Nothing gets returned

Comment: Please check if your disk is not full

Comment: The disk is not full

Comment: Did you try a reboot? Maybe hangs the pid file?

Comment: I already tried rebooting the server. Same problem still

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling mysql worked for me: `apt-get remove mysql-server`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 7):

Check the MySQL logs in /var/log or possibly in /var/lib/mysql.

My bet is that the reason it "hangs" is because its doing a repair of some sort on tables that could have gotten corrupted. I've seen "mysql" take 20 minutes or longer to "start"... How long have you given it before assuming it's "hung"?

See if the logs indicate anything. Also, after starting mysql once, try running this to verify MySQL is, in fact, running:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but look at the last line I wrote with the ps -ef, nothing gets returned even after I 'start' mysql

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yah, nothing special

Comment: Where can I can the mysqld.sock?  It's missing from /var/run/mysqld

Answer (score 4):

The best way to debug this type of thing is to directly run

```
sudo mysqld
```

That's the only way to see startup errors.  (For some reason, they aren't written to any of the mysql logs).  Often you can see it's failing to load a binlog or having problems getting to a certain directory.

Comment: You sure that `sudo` belongs there?!

Comment: running this without `sudo` will give you more accurate feedback unless you are launching `mysqld` as `sudo`. 

MySQL has global and user specific settings, so `sudo` would only give you information for the root user.

Comment: I was trying to restart mysql but could not do so as the secure path mentioned in the config was not there. only this command could tell me the real problem.